# Given a cube rotated around the center, how would you calculate the lowest possible point from the center?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, rotations

Imagine a cube of any arbitrary size.

Furthermore, imagine the cube can be rotated in any dimension: X/Y/Z.

Given both the rotations and the size, how can you calculate the difference between the center and the lowest point of the cube? (Example: center[z] - lowestZCordinateOfAnyCorner)

For example, let's say there is a cube of size 100 (width/height/depth are the same). If there are no rotations (XRot = 0, YRot = 0, ZRot = 0), then the lowest point is 50 units away from the center. This is because the calculation occurs from the center of the cube to the center of the lowest face of the cube.

On the other hand, with the same cube, if it is rotated so one corner is pointed as low as possible (XRot = 45deg, YRot = 45deg, ZRot = 45deg), the lowest point would be the corner. Using the distance from the center of cube to face (50) and distance of center of face to corner (sqrt(50^2 + 50^2)), we can calculate the distance from cube center to corner using the pythagorean theorem (sqrt((50^2 + 50^2) + 50^2) = ~86.602).

Now my question is, how would you calculate the lowest point of a cube with any arbitrary combination of X/Y/Z rotations? Another way to look at it is, if I take a rod, and move it straight down from the center of the cube, how long until the end of the rod is at the same level as the lowest corner?

Comment: If rotations are about the centre, you already gave the answer, as a vertex is the point in a cube which is farthest from the centre.

Comment: @Aretino My apologies, I suppose I didn't word things correctly. While the corner is the farthest away, the difference between the global "Z position" of the cube's center and the "Z position" of the lowest corner is different depending on the rotations. 

For example, if just the XRot is 90, the difference is ~70.71. Does that make sense?

Comment: I see now, sorry for misunderstanding. You can simply compute the z coordinate of all eight vertices after rotation, and take the lowest lying.

Comment: @Aretino How to calculate the position of the vertex relative to the center?

Comment: That depends on how the rotation is given. What do you exactly mean by "an arbitrary combination of X/Y/Z rotations?"

Comment: If the rotation is given as a product of three rotations about the axes, then you can find the answer here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix#In_three_dimensions

Comment: Be warned, however, that the rotation you described: "XRot = 45°, YRot = 45°, ZRot = 45°" does not carry a vertex of the cube on the Z axis.